# Why can't I see my favorite locations anymore when saving a file?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, file

Here is a picture of my finder

[image]

On the left, there are my `favorites` which is very handy for quickly accessing important folders. I used to have access to the `favorites` when saving a file or when searching a file to send by email.

## Problem

Recently and with no apparent reason, I can't see the `favorites` anymore when trying to save a file or when trying to select a file to send attached to an email. (I can still see the `favorites` when navigating with the `Finder`).

Here is what it looks like when trying to save a Microsofot Word document

[image]

Here is what it looks like when trying to select a file to attach on an email (via GMail)

[image]

## Question

How can I get my `favorites` back?

## OS

I am on a desktop running on Mac OSX 10.11.3

Comment: It is a duplicate indeed. Thank you! As my post may help redirect future users, I will just wait for you guys to close it (unless you think I'd better delete it).